# If $B$ is a closed subset of a maetric space, can we show that $\partial B^\circ=\partial B$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a metric space and $B\subseteq E$ be closed. Can we show that $\partial B^\circ=\partial B$?

The claim is not true without closedness: For example, if $E=\mathbb R$ and $B=\mathbb Q$, then $B^\circ=\emptyset$ and $\partial B=\mathbb R$.

Comment: It isn't true with closedness either. Take $B$ a closed interval. Its boundary is just the two endpoints, and their interior is empty. Did you mean $^\circ$ to denote the [relative interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior), or something like that?

Comment: @Conifold Please take note of my comment below [Brian M. Scott's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3812503/47771).

Comment: You should put that into the question. By definition of manifold with boundary, $\partial M$ is a manifold without boundary. Since topological and manifold boundaries coincide this is trivially true.

Comment: @Conifold Huh? I've asked a separate question for the manifold thing. I just thought it would hold more generally, which is why I've asked this question. Regarding what you wrote about the manifold: In general, the topological and manifold boundary do *not* coincide. And as I wrote in the other question, the manifold interior is a manifold *without* boundary and hence $\partial M^\circ=\emptyset\ne\partial M$. So, I don't know why you think it's trivially true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set, which is closed in $\Bbb R$: $\operatorname{int}B=\varnothing$, so $\operatorname{bdry}\operatorname{int}B=\varnothing$, but $\operatorname{bdry}B=B$.

Comment: Does the situation change when $B$ is the closure of an open set?

Comment: The situation I'm actually interested in is the one that I've described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3812514/47771. Is there anything special in that situation?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I honestly couldn’t say: I’ve always stayed away from manifolds, differential topology, etc. and stuck with general and set-theoretic topology.